# PL/SQL input validation using API

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I'm new to Oracle Apex and PL/SQL. I am using a REST API called numVerify (documentation [here](https://numverify.com/documentation)) to check if the phone number that a user submits in a form is a valid phone number. I created a validation process of type "function body (returning boolean)". I wrote this code in an attempt to send the request url to the web service and parse the JSON response (I need the first key/value data), but I know there's most definitely a few large errors with it. If anyone could take a look and help me out I would very much appreciate it.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried your code? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: I’ve used the button at the top of the editor to validate the code. When I try to complete the form that runs on this code I get an error that says “error processing validation”. In the browser JavaScript console there is an error “the message port closed before a response was received”. I checked the activity from my account on numVerify and there was no logged attempt to use it.

Comment: Using the developer bar at the bottom of the screen, enable debugging mode, run your page and afterwards take a look at the debugging info. There should be more information than "error processing validation". It could be anything like an Access Control List problem for example (Oracle DB Firewall).

Comment: I found that my request was blocked by the ACL. Currently trying to fix it.